# How to add publisher to biblatex style (fiwi)?

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with [`biblatex-fiwi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-fiwi) and the `fiwi2` option:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=fiwi2,
]{biblatex}
```

I am super content with the style, just publishers are omitted in the bibliography.

I would love to see the publisher added at the end (Sage manually entered, bold)

```
Hofstede, Geert (2003): Culture’s Consequences: Comparing Values, Behaviors, Institutions
and Organizations Across Nations. 2. Aufl. Sage
```

How to get the publisher, which is in the `*.bib` file, into this bibliography?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can't you just add `publisher=true` to the load options?  See p. 7 of the documentation.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks! Totally worked. Sorry, I just browsed the documentation's headlines, but should have searched for keywords...

Answer (score 7):

[`biblatex-fiwi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-fiwi) allows load options, in this case you just have to add `publisher=true` to your `biblatex` options. It should read like that then:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=fiwi2,
publisher=true
]{biblatex}
```